# Do I need CSRF token if I'm using Bearer JWT?

Tags: angularjs, express, cookies, jwt, csrf

**Context**: Angular site is hosted on S3 behind CloudFront, separate from Express server that is used as API and almost all requests are XMLHttpRequests. All requests are sent without cookies (withCredentials = false by default) and I use JWT Bearer token for authentication by taking it from cookies in angular and placing to `Authorization` header (This technique is kind of what is described in [CSRF Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Cookie-to-Header_Token)).

On Express site I do not allow `Cookie` header in `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`.

Cookies have `secure: true` flag, and are NOT `httpOnly` because I need to manually access them in angular.

Also I've read in [this Medium article](https://medium.com/node-security/cross-site-request-forgery-mitigation-for-express-js-apps-made-easy-using-the-same-site-cookie-flag-e19ee7d5b513) that JSON-Web-Tokens(JWT )/Bearer Tokens

> is without a doubt one of the best methods of preventing CSRF

**Question 1**: Will I add extra security if I'll add X-XSRF-Token header to each request and for example make the mechanism stateless by checking for that same value in JWT payload? (I'we read about it in [this thread](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/115766/is-a-jwt-usable-as-a-csrf-token))

**Question 2**: Do I actually need extra security efforts agains CSRF taking all that I described?

Comment: If you are not attaching your cookies automatically to each request then.you are not vulnerable to CSRF/XSRF

Comment: What does attaching cookies automatically to each request?

Comment: @user805981 Attaching cookies automatically is a default behaviour for browser.

Comment: I found a good anwser for this question: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/170414/189759